# php://temp copy it to a file?

Tags: php, file, copy

I have some code that create a tmp file using `php://temp` ...

For debugging purpose and learning as well, I would like to save/copy into a defined file.
So there is any easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `stream_get_contents` or `fwrite` when working with large files

```
//Somecode wrting to temp
$tmp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
fwrite($tmp, 'test');
rewind($tmp);


// Read and save to log.txt 
file_put_contents("log.txt",stream_get_contents($tmp));
```

Large File Implementation

```
set_time_limit(0);

$file = "log.txt";
$final = fopen($file, "w+");

while ( ! feof($tmp) ) {
    fwrite($final, fgets($tmp));
}

fclose($tmp);
fclose($final);
```

Comment: `stream_copy_to_stream` may be as well interesting

Comment: Does it could cause out of memory error, if the tmp file is very big ? shouldn't be better write it line by line ?

Comment: Depends on what you are reading and copying  .. you can `fread` & `fwrite` it line by line .. in large contents ...